# Java class major version

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jvm

I am using sun/oracle jdk 1.6.0_32 and the javac compiler seems to create class files for a target 1.5 jvm not 1.6.  It won't accept -source 1.6 -target 1.6.  Looking at the generated class file with javap shows a major version: 49 not 50 as I would expect.  Eclipse Indigo correctly creates 1.6 compliant class files with major version: 50.  I first noticed this when using ant 1.8.2 in eclipse and was unable to set the source or target attributes to 1.6.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Addendum

I only have 1 jdk (1.6.0_32) installed.  From the command line I get the following.

```
ken@kryten:~/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin/com/kwcons$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 ken ken 4096 2012-06-28 16:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ken ken 4096 2012-06-28 16:46 ..
ken@kryten:~/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin/com/kwcons$ javac -d /home/ken/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin -version /home/ken/projects/simpleHelloWorld/src/com/kwcons/HelloWorld.java
javac 1.6.0_32
ken@kryten:~/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin/com/kwcons$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 ken ken 4096 2012-06-28 16:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ken ken 4096 2012-06-28 16:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ken ken  441 2012-06-28 16:50 HelloWorld.class
ken@kryten:~/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin/com/kwcons$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/javap -verbose HelloWorld |grep major
  major version: 49
ken@kryten:~/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin/com/kwcons$
```

This is what I get if I use -source and -target.

```
ken@kryten:~/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin/com/kwcons$ javac -d /home/ken/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin -version -source 1.6 -target 1.6 /home/ken/projects/simpleHelloWorld/src/com/kwcons/HelloWorld.java
javac 1.6.0_32
javac: invalid source release: 1.6
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system

ken@kryten:~/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin/com/kwcons$
```

I get the same output from ant in eclipse.

Comment: How many copies of the JDK do you have installed?  What's the output of `javac -version`?

Comment: I'm using 1.6.0_21 and it creates 1.6 classes perfectly well. Have you considered filing a bug report?

Comment: Same q as Jonathan - Please post the result of "javac -version".  I have a hard time believing you're actually getting the Java 6 version of javac.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
1) In ant script specify jdk version

2) Write the follwing javac target inside your "compile" target,

runtime-libs:: It will point your project lib directory. declared in properties.

```
<javac
bootclasspath="${runtime-libs}/rt.jar"
target="1.6"
source="1.6"
includeJavaRuntime="false"
includeAntRuntime="false"
debug="yes"
destdir="${build-dir}">
<classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
<src path="${code}"/>
</javac>
```

Comment: Tried this but I get     [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ken/projects/simpleHelloWorld/bin
    [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.6
I have only one jdk (1.6.0_32) and I believe it is using the correct javac.  I have also just compiled the file in terminal and I get a class file that javap says is major version:49

Comment: I am still getting used to the protocol on SO.  I have placed more details in the thread as an answer.

Comment: on command prompt run command "java -version", and check what is your java version.